# von Neumann Entropy of a joint state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, density-operator, information

**Definition 1** *The von Neumann entropy* of a density matrix is given by $$S(\rho) := - 
\mathrm{Tr}[\rho \ln \rho] = H[\lambda (\rho)] $$ where $H[\lambda (\rho)] $ is the *Shannon entropy* of the set of probabilities $\lambda (\rho) $ (which are eigenvalues of the density operator $\rho$).

**Definition 2** If a system is prepared in the ensemble $\{ p_j, \rho_j \} $ then we define the Holevo $\chi$ quantity for the ensemble by $$\chi := S(\rho) - \sum_j p_j S(\rho_j) $$

**Short Question :** Let $A$ and $B$ be two quantum systems in a state of the form $$\rho^{(AB)} = \sum_i q_i |a_{i}^{(A)} \rangle \langle a_{i}^{(A)} | \otimes \rho_{i}^{(B)} $$
where the states $|a_{i}^{(A)} \rangle$ are orthogonal. What property of the von Neumann entropy implies that the von Neumann entropy of the joint state is $$S(\rho^{(AB)}) = H(\vec{q}) + \sum_i q_i S(\rho_{i}^{(B)})? $$

**Proposal:** I'm pretty sure it makes use of the following properties of von Neumann entropy: $$S(\rho_{A} \otimes \rho_{B}) = S(\rho_{A}) + S(\rho_{B})$$ and if $\rho_{A} = \sum_{x} p_x | \phi_x \rangle \langle \phi_x|$ then $$S(\rho_{A} \otimes \rho_{B}) = H(X) + S(\rho_{B})$$ where $X = \{| \phi_x \rangle, p_x \}$.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\rho^{(AB)} = \sum_i q_i |a_i^{(A)}\rangle \langle a_i^{(A)}| \otimes \rho_i^{(B)} \tag 1
$$
Note that subsystem $A$ and $B$ are separable, let
$$
\rho^{(B)}_i = \sum_j \lambda^j_i |{b_i^j}^{(B)}\rangle \langle {b_i^j}^{(B)}|. \tag 2
$$
Substitute equation $(2)$ into $(1)$:
$$
\eqalignno{
S(\rho^{(AB)}) &= -\sum_{ij} q_i \lambda_i^j \ln(q_i \lambda_i^j) \\
               &= -\sum_{ij} q_i \lambda_i^j (\ln q_i + \ln \lambda_i^j) \\
               &= -\sum_i q_i \ln q_i - \sum_i q_i \sum_j \lambda_i^j \ln 
                   \lambda_i^j \\
               &= H(\vec q) + \sum_i q_i S(\rho_i^{(B)}). &(3)
}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just want to confirm the first step after substituting (2) into (1) i.e.
$$S(\rho^{(AB)}) = -\sum_{ij} q_i \lambda_i^j \ln(q_i \lambda_i^j).$$ Is the reasoning as follows: After substituting (2) into (1) we obtain 
$$\begin{align}
\rho^{(AB)} &= \sum_{i}\sum_{j}q_{i} \lambda_{i}^{j} | a_{i}^{(A)} \rangle \langle a_{i}^{(A)}| \otimes \sum_{j}\lambda_{i}^{j}|b_{i}^{j(B)} \rangle \langle b_{i}^{j(B)}| \\
 &= \sum_{i}\sum_{j}q_{i}\lambda_{i}^{j}|a_{i}^{(A)} \rangle \langle a_{i}^{(A)}| \otimes |b_{i}^{j(B)} \rangle \langle b_{i}^{j(B)}|
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hence we use note that since $|a_{i}^{(A)} \rangle$ diagonalizes $\rho^{A}$ and $|b_{i}^{j(B)} \rangle$ diagonalizes $\rho^{B}$ it follows that $|a_{i}^{A} \rangle \otimes |b_{i}^{j(B)} \rangle$ diagonalizes $\rho^{(AB)}$with eigenvalues $q_{i} \lambda_{i}^{j}$.Hence we apply the definition of von Neumann entropy to this?

Comment: Yeah,  the key is that A and B are separable. It's more complicated when systems are correlated.